# kendo UI grid in SharePoint 2010 - the column Grouping feature does not work (drag'n'drop issue ?)

Tags: sharepoint, kendo-grid

in SharePoint 2010, I have an ASPX page with a kendo UI grid.
I have configured the grid to have the column Grouping feature turned ON.

```
groupable: true
```

the grid loads, and the toolstrip above the grid, tells user to drag'n'drop columns, in order to have them grouped.

However, I cannot drag'n'drop column header: the 'drag' does not start.

The same code works fine outside of SharePoint (in a ASP.NET project).

It looks like SharePoint javascript is preventing kendo UI from receiving the 'drag' event ?

note: the feature to re-order columns also does not work (also because the 'drag' operation does not start)

There are no browser errors (in Chrome console, OR in IE9 console).

has anyone experienced similar issue - or maybe you know how to prevent SharePoint from blocking the 'drag' event ?